# Failed to open //usr/lib/opkg/info/luci-i18n-unblockmusic-zh-cn.list: No such file or directory

Tags: opkg

try to install package in FusionWrt by `opkg install`, error occur:

```bash
$ opkg install shadow-common           
Package shadow-common (4.8.1-3) installed in root is up to date.
Collected errors:
 * pkg_get_installed_files: Failed to open //usr/lib/opkg/info/luci-i18n-unblockmusic-zh-cn.list: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by copy the file from `/rom/usr/lib/opkg/`

```bash
cp /rom/usr/lib/opkg/info/luci-i18n-unblockmusic-zh-cn.list /usr/lib/opkg/info/luci-i18n-unblockmusic-zh-cn.list
```